# How do I bind table values to a Map and post with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an entry form where users select a subset of items which populate a table. I need to bind each row's first and and third column value to a key and value, respectively, enter them into a Map<Integer, Integer> passed in through the controller, and post the data. I've poured through many different solutions online and have yet to find one that works. The map always returns empty.

Wrapper class for Map

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ItemForm {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Controllers

```
@GetMapping(...)
public String showItemPage(Model model) {
    ...
    model.addAttribute("itemForm", new ItemForm());
    ...
}

@PostMapping(...)
public String processItemUpdate(@ModelAttribute("itemForm") ItemForm itemForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

Template

```
<tr th:each="item : *{items}">
    <td>
        <input type="text" th:value="${item.key}">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{items[__${item.key}__]}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I understand that I will need something like `th:field="*{items[__${item.key}__]}"` to access the map, but as to extracting and combining the key-value pair I'm a bit lost.

edit:
Is something along these lines possible?

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ItemFormPair {
    private int ID, quantity;
}

@Getter @Setter
public class ItemForm {
    private List<ItemFormPair> items = new ArrayList<>();
}


<tr th:each="item, stat : *{items}">
    <td>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{items[__${stat.index}__].ID}">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{items[__${stat.index}__].quantity}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

edit:
I don't really want to spend any more time on this problem and there doesn't appear to be an elegant solution available so I'm simply going to use an Ajax POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You bound the single key/values of the map to the form but not the map itself. That won't work that way. I'm quite sure there is no way to get the map as whole piece back from the form. Maybe with a converter.

An alternative could be to assign name/id to the input fields and read all key/values back to map in the processItemUpdate method:

This solution works on my site. I redefined my answer more precisely:

input.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head />

<body>

    <form th:action="@{/inputPost}" method="post" th:fragment="form">

        <table>
            <tr th:each="item,iter : ${itemForm.items.entrySet()}">

                <td><input type="text" th:id="${iter.index + '.ID'}"
                    th:name="${iter.index + '.ID'}" th:value="${item.key}"></td>

                <td><input type="text" th:id="${iter.index + '.VALUE'}"
                    th:name="${iter.index + '.VALUE'}" th:value="${item.value}"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" /> <input type="submit"
            name="Add" value="Add new Line" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
    

<body>


    <table border="1">
        <tr th:each="item : ${itemForm.items.entrySet()}">

            <td th:text="${item.key}"></td>

            <td th:text="${item.value}"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/inputForm")
public String dummy(Model model) {

    ItemForm form = new ItemForm();
    form.getItems().put(form.getItems().size(), 42);

    model.addAttribute("itemForm", form);

    return "input";
}

@PostMapping("/inputPost")
public String processItemUpdate(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    ItemForm form = new ItemForm();

    String operation = null;

    for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : params.entrySet()) {

        if (entry.getKey().endsWith(".ID")) { // only react on ID values. The values will be directly fetched from
                                                // map
            String[] tokens = StringUtils.split(entry.getKey(), ".");

            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            Integer idValue = Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue()[0]);

            String[] value = params.get(id + ".VALUE"); // fetch the value to defined ID
            Integer valueValue = Integer.parseInt(value[0]);

            form.getItems().put(idValue, valueValue);

        } else if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Send")) { // determine operation

            operation = "send";

        } else if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) { // determine operation

            operation = "add";
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("itemForm", form);

    if (operation.equals("add")) { // add a new line and resend form again
        form.getItems().put(form.getItems().size(), 42);
        return "input";
    }

    return "success";

}
```

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately. The parameter map doesn't appear to hold any values even after modifying the template.

Comment: @bliss This refined example should work and meet your demands.